# how to read xml files in C# ?

Tags: c#, xml

I have a code which reads an xml file. There are some parts I dont understand.
From my understanding , the code will create an xml file with 2  elements, 
"Product" and "OtherDetails" . How come we only have to use  writer.WriteEndElement();
once when we used writer.WriteStartElement twice ? , shouldn't we close each 
writer.WriteStartElement statement with a writer.WriteEndElement() statement ?

```
using System.Xml;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Indent = true;

        XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("Products.xml", settings);
        writer.WriteStartDocument();
        writer.WriteComment("This file is generated by the program.");
        writer.WriteStartElement("Product");          // first s
        writer.WriteAttributeString("ID", "001");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("Name", "Soap"); 
        writer.WriteElementString("Price", "10.00")  

        // Second Element 
        writer.WriteStartElement("OtherDetails");
        writer.WriteElementString("BrandName", "X Soap");
        writer.WriteElementString("Manufacturer", "X Company");
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndDocument();

        writer.Flush();
        writer.Close();
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("Products.xml");

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element
            && reader.Name == "Product")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ID = " + reader.GetAttribute(0));  
                Console.WriteLine("Name = " + reader.GetAttribute(1));

                while (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement)
                {
                    reader.Read();
                    if (reader.Name == "Price")
                    {
                        while (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement)
                        {
                            reader.Read();
                            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Price = {0:C}", Double.Parse(reader.Value));
                            }
                        }

                        reader.Read();

                    } //end if


                    if (reader.Name == "OtherDetails")
                    {
                        while (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement)
                        {
                            reader.Read();
                            if (reader.Name == "BrandName")
                            {
                                while (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement)
                                {
                                    reader.Read();
                                    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine("Brand Name = " + reader.Value);
                                    }
                                }
                                reader.Read();
                            } //end if

                            if (reader.Name == "Manufacturer")
                            {
                                while (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement)
                                {
                                    reader.Read();
                                    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine("Manufacturer = " + reader.Value);
                                    }
                                }

                            } //end if
                        }
                    } //end if
                } //end while
            } //end if

        } //end while
    }
}
```

I don't get this part:

```
if (reader.Name == "OtherDetails")
{
    while (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement)
    {
        reader.Read();
        if (reader.Name == "BrandName")
        {
            while (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement)
            {
                reader.Read();
                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Brand Name = " + reader.Value);
                }
            }
```

notice how the condition `while (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement)` has been used twice ?

why is that we don't have to specify

`if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element for OtherDetails)` as we did for Product,

like this

```
if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element
&& reader.Name == "OtherDetails")
{}
```

Comment: Do you *have* to use XmlWriter? If you can use LINQ to XML, it will be much, much simpler to code.

Comment: I prefer using XmlDocument to read XML files. You can loop easily loop through each node and the child nodes of each node.

Comment: @HH Have you tried Linq2Xml? All you said can be done much easier with it.

Comment: @I4V I haven't tried Linq2Xml, but I've had no problems with XmlDocument (although I have heard lots of complaints).

Comment: @HH I also have no problem using pure TCP to connect to Web Servers, but I prefer to use WebClient, HttpClient etc. and let them to do all the dirty things for me.

Comment: To answer your question about why that line of code is used twice, it's because `reader.Read()` advances the internal index of the reader, thus changing its value, so you need to re-evaluate if what the reader has is what you want.

Comment: @I4V That's not the first time I've heard that complaint about XmlDocument, but I've never understood it. For me it's been simply create the XmlDocument, then load the nodes from a file. After that I just use foreach loops to access each node. I can't imagine it being much simpler.

Comment: @HH then try Linq2Xml, Better, stay tuned. probably there will be a question about parsing an xml soon, and answer it. (BTW: this is not *complaint* about XmlDocument, just to point out to easier ways)

Answer (score 3):

To answer your first question:

As the [MSDN documentation for XmlWriter.WriteEndDocument()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.writeenddocument.aspx) says:

> Closes any open elements or attributes and puts the writer back in the Start state.

So it will automatically close any open elements for you. In fact, you can remove the call to `WriteEndElement()` altogether and it will still work ok.

And as people are saying in the comments above, you should perhaps consider using Linq-to-XML.

It can make things much easier. For example, to create the XML structure from your program using Linq-to-XML you can do this:

```
var doc = new XDocument(
    new XElement("Product",
            new XAttribute("ID", "001"), new XAttribute("Name", "Soap"),
        new XElement("Price", 10.01),
        new XElement("OtherDetails", 
            new XElement("BrandName", "X Soap"),
            new XElement("Manufacturer", "X Company"))));

File.WriteAllText("Products.xml", doc.ToString());
```

If you were reading data from the XML, you can use [`var doc = XDocument.Load("Filename.xml")`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343181.aspx) to load the XML from a file, and then getting the data out is as simple as:

```
double price     = double.Parse(doc.Descendants("Price").Single().Value);
string brandName = doc.Descendants("BrandName").Single().Value;
```

Or alternatively (casting):

```
double price     = (double) doc.Descendants("Price").Single();
string brandName = (string) doc.Descendants("BrandName").Single();
```

(In case you're wondering how on earth we can cast an object of type XElement like that: It's because [a load of explict conversion operators are defined for XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.op_explicit.aspx).)

Answer (score 0):

If you need anything strait forward (no reading or research), here is what I did:

I recently wrote a custom XML parsing method for my MenuStrip for WinForms (it had hundreds of items and XML was my best bet).

```
// load the document
// I loaded mine from my C# resource file called TempResources
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(TempResources.Menu)));

// get the root element
// (var is an auto token, it becomes what ever you assign it)
var elements = doc.Root.Elements();

// iterate through the child elements
foreach (XElement node in elements)
{
     // if you know the name of the attribute, you can call it
     // mine was 'name'
     // (if you don't know, you can call node.Attributes() - this has the name and value)
     Console.WriteLine("Loading list: {0}", node.Attribute("name").Value);

     // in my case, every child had additional children, and them the same
     // *.Cast<XElement>() would give me the array in a datatype I can work with
     // menu_recurse(...) is just a resursive helper method of mine
     menu_recurse(node.Elements().Cast<XElement>().ToArray()));
}
```

(My answer can also be found here: [Reading an XML File With Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20668413/reading-an-xml-file-with-linq/20669837#20669837) - though it unfortunately is not Linq)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose if you want to read an xml file we need to use a dataset,because xml file internally converts into datatables using a dataset.Use the following line of code to access the file and to bind the dataset with the xml data.

```
    DataSet ds=new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXml(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Labels.xml");
```

DataSet comprises of many datatables,count of those datatables depends on number of Parent Child Tags in an xml file