# Reading an XML File With Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have looked all over but could only find results that had Child Elements in the file and no attributes! I took some advice from a previous post of mine to use Linq to write to the file and I did.

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists("Guardian.re") == false)
{
    //.re is the file extension that is used

    XDocument doc = new XDocument(
      new XElement("Guardian",
      new XAttribute("IGN",IGN),
      new XAttribute("Hours",hours),
      new XAttribute("Why",WhyRank),
      new XAttribute("Qualifications",Qualify)
       )
     );
}
```

Now here is the XML that I had it generate

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Guardian>
  <IGN>IGN</IGN>
  <Hours>Hours</Hours>
  <Why>Why</Why>
  <Qualifications>Qualifications</Qualifications>
</Guardian>
```

Now, I want to display these values in a listbox as follows

```
Guardian
IGN
Hours
WhyReason
Qualifications
```

Comment: Can you not load the `xml` into a `dataset` then manipulate the structure for the `listbox`?

Comment: @Greg What is a dataset?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.data.dataset%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: @Greg [SerializableAttribute]
public class DataSet : MarshalByValueComponent, IListSource, 
 IXmlSerializable, ISupportInitializeNotification, ISupportInitialize, ISerializable How can I use this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load("Guardian.re"); // load your file
var items = xdoc.Root.Elements().Select(e => (string)e).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote a custom XML parsing method for my MenuStrip for WinForms (it had hundreds of items and XML was my best bet). This may not be Linq, but here is how I did it (may it be of use):

```
// load the document
// I loaded mine from my C# resource file called TempResources
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(TempResources.Menu)));

// get the root element
// in your XML example, this would be 'Guardian'
// (var is an auto token, it becomes what ever you assign it)
var elements = doc.Root.Elements();

// iterate through the child elements
foreach (XElement node in elements)
{
     // if you know the name of the attribute, you can call it
     // mine was 'name'
     Console.WriteLine("Loading list: {0}", node.Attribute("name").Value);
     // your code may look something like this:
     // listBox.Items.Add(node.Attribute("IGN").Value);

     // in my case, every child had additional children, and them the same
     // *.Cast<XElement>() would give me the array in a datatype I can work with
     // menu_recurse(...) is just a resursive helper method of mine
     menu_recurse(node.Elements().Cast<XElement>().ToArray()));
}
```

Now, if you don't know the name of the attribute, you can get it by calling `node.Attributes()` which will return an array of XAttributes. This call will hold the name and value of each attribute in the given node. (Use a foreach loop)

**[EDIT]**
Here is the XML file I used (as a demonstrative example):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menus>
     <menuset name="main">...</menuset>
     <menuset name="second">...</menuset>
</menus>
```

`<menus>` is the root;
`<menuset>` is a child XElement;
`name="..."` is an XAttribute of XElement;

Comment: @user2678408 I'm not quite sure what changes were made, however, after reviewing over what you already have again, I came to realize that your code and the 'resulting' XML do not match. The resulting XML from your code would actually look more like this: `<Guardian IGN="..." Hours="..." Why="..." Qualifications="..."></Guardian>`

Answer (score 0):

The items you seem to want to display are a mixture of an Element name, attribute names and attribute values. If you have control of the xml generation process, it would be much easier to create all the things you want in the list as individual elements, then all you need do is use LINQ to query all the elements.